# Post request with requests library?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

In order to stream data, I enter the following to the command line:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer {my_access_token}" 
https://example1.example2.com/example3/example4/example5/example6
```

I get:

```
<data>
    <sessionid>{sessionid}</sessionid>
    <url>https://example1.example2.com/example3/example4/
    example5</url>
</data>
```

Then, I enter:

```
curl -X POST -d "person=Adam&sessionid={sessionid}" 
https://example6.example2.com/example3/example4/example5
```

In response, my data stream is outputted continuously in the terminal.

However, I would like to make the same requests programmatically using Python. I use the requests library. I have the following code:

```
import httplib
import urllib
import requests

person = "Adam"
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('example1.example2.com', 443, 
timeout 
= 30)

# Headers

headers = {"Accept":"application/json",
"Authorization":"Bearer {my_access_token}"

# Send synchronously

connection.request('POST', '/example3/example4/example5/example6', 
None, 
headers)
#Connection for streaming here
try:
    response = connection.getresponse()
    content = response.read()
    # Success
    # print('Response status ' + str(response.status))
    stringOption = content.decode('UTF-8')
    json_objOption = json.loads(stringOption)
    # Put the data into a text file
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_objOption, outfile)
    sessionid = json_objOption["data"]["sessionid"]
except httplib.HTTPException, e:
# Exception
    print('Exception during request')

httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'

API_ENDPOINT = 
"https://example6.example2.com/example3/example4/example5"

headers = {"Accept":"application/json"}

data = {'person': person,
'sessionid': sessionid}


r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers, data = 
data)
print(r.text)
print(r)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

None of the print statements output anything. There is no output after running this script. Why is this the case?

Comment: Why are you using `httplib` for the first request and `requests` for the second (and importing `urllib`, but not using it)? If by "no output" you mean the `print(r.text)` does not print anything, I suggest inspecting `r`.

Comment: What do you recommend for inspecting r?

Comment: See the [documentation for `requests.Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). `r.status_code` would be useful. `requsets.Response.__repr__` also includes the status code, so you could just `print(r)`. You could also use a tool like Wireshark to observe both requests.

Comment: ^Post edited accordingly above.

Comment: what is real url ? `requests` has option `stream=` and [methods to read stream in chunks](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests)